# Decoding data from a MIDI controller as eight buttons

Tags: python

I thought about using loops but I don't know how I would do this. if I used for loops would it work the same way as the code down below?

```
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="6":
    print("Button1")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="7":
    print("Button2")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="8":
    print("Button3")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="9":
    print("Button4")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="A":
    print("Button5")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="B":
    print("Button6")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="C":
    print("Button7")
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1" and data[-4]=="D":
    print("Button8")
```

EDIT: When I press a button it prints out the number ex. If I press button one it prints button one. And it would work the same for other at and given time. It'll be on a while true loop.

Comment: What is `data`? Is it a string? A list? What is special about positions -8, -5, and -4? Could you give some context for why this code exists and what it accomplishes?

Comment: @200_success Data is the data being sent from my MIDI controller. I'm making a synth. The negative numbers are the table's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first two query's are always the same, you can check that in one `if`.

```
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1":
    if data[-4]=="6":
        print("Button1")
    if data[-4]=="7":
        print("Button2")
    if data[-4]=="8":
        print("Button3")
    if data[-4]=="9":
        print("Button4")
    if data[-4]=="A":
        print("Button5")
    if data[-4]=="B":
        print("Button6")
    if data[-4]=="C":
        print("Button7")
    if data[-4]=="D":
        print("Button8")
```

After this I'd personally use a dictionary. This isn't much different than using an if, but it's a little cleaner in my opinion. It also makes the code a little easier when you want to expand on it too.

```
buttons = {
    "6": "Button1"
    "7": "Button2"
    "8": "Button3"
    "9": "Button4"
    "A": "Button5"
    "B": "Button6"
    "C": "Button7"
    "D": "Button8"
}
if data[-8]=="B" and data[-5]=="1":
    print(buttons[data[-4]])
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Use a `dict` for lookups

When doing lookups, Python provides an associative array data structure called a `dict`.  Your stacked ifs can be cleanly written as a dict lookup like:

```
button_text = {
    ("B", "1", "6"): "Button1",
    ("B", "1", "7"): "Button2",
    ("B", "1", "8"): "Button3",
    ("B", "1", "9"): "Button4",
    ("B", "1", "A"): "Button5",
    ("B", "1", "B"): "Button6",
    ("B", "1", "C"): "Button7",
    ("B", "1", "D"): "Button8",
}

print(button_text[data[-8], data[-5], data[-4]])
```